# Animate and add class at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to add a class with `top` and `left` properties for animation, but the `div` just shifts to the added class attribute without animating.

```css
#myClass.move {
    top:100px;
    left:100px; 
}
```

The goal is to have the animation happen right when the class is added and animate based on the properties of the added class.

```
var shiftTop = parseInt($(".move").css("top")); 
var shiftLeft = parseInt($(".move").css("left")); 

$("#myClass").addClass("move").animate({top: "-="+shiftTop, left: "-="+shiftLeft}, 1000, function() {});
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**jQueryUI**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/addClass).

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tg37u/)

```
$("#myClass").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("move", 1000);
});​
```

Comment: I know this is a little off topic, but does anybody know why the animation is so choppy in safari? Im running version 5.1.7.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myClass').animate({top: "-="+shiftTop, left: "-="+shiftLeft}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).addClass('#myClass');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible:

**Add class before animate**:
`$("#myClass").addClass("move").animate({top: "-="+shiftTop, left: "-="+shiftLeft}, 1000);`
[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kb2yJ/2/)

**Add class after animate**:

```
$("#myClass").animate({top: "-="+shiftTop, left: "-="+shiftLeft}, 1000, function() {
    $(this).addClass('move');
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kb2yJ/3/)

Comment: +1, this should have been the answer, without any extra libraries. And it was just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have an element with class `.move` in your document already, from which to read the `shiftTop` and `shiftLeft` values.

If all you need to do is change the `top` and `left` attributes you can remove the `addClass` step entirely, since the `animate` function adds them inline. If you do need the class applied after, do it in the `animate` callback.

Depending on your compatibility requirements you could also do this entirely with CSS, using [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).